# Form not submitting values inside <div>

Tags: html, forms, submit, frontend

I am working with Laravel 5.4 Framework and I get this issue when the `form` does not submit anything except the `csrf_token()`.

If I put an `input` outside of those `<div>` it will work and submit it, otherwise the browser (Chrome) will only submit the token, as if everything inside the `<div>` is not part of the form.

How can I submit all the data while using Bootstrap's `form-group` divs? The layout is not the problem as it does not work even when removing it.

@extends('layouts.master')

```
@section('content')


    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 1%">
    <p>Welcome, {{$user->name}}, here you can submit a new company for our database.</p>

    <form name="suggestCompanyForm" method="post">

        {{csrf_field()}}

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="companyName">Company Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="companyName" aria-describedby="companyNameHelp" placeholder="Enter company name">
            <small id="companyNameHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Enter the company's name you would like to suggest</small>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="companyEmail">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="companyEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Enter the company contact email.</small>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="selectCategory">Select main category</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="selectCategory">
                <option>Food&Drink</option>
                <option>Cosmetics</option>
                <option>Electronics</option>
                <option>Consumer Goods</option>
                <option>Services</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description">Company description.</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="description" rows="5"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="logo">File input</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="logo" aria-describedby="logoHelp">
            <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Add company logo.</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="checkbox" id="check" class="form-check-input">
                I agree that my submission follows the website rules.
            </label>
        </div>
        <button id="submitCompany" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>


@endsection
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your form inputs are not being submitted because you didn't give them names ...

Try

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="description" id="description" rows="5"></textarea>
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks.

Comment: Glad i could be of help

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the action attribute to the form tag.
Edit this line

```
<form name="suggestCompanyForm" method="post">
```

to

```
<form name="suggestCompanyForm" action = "<url-for-the-submission>"  method="post">
```

.You will also need to add this

```
name="name_of_input_to_submit"
```

to each input not only the textarea and you are also uploading a file you have to add this to the form tag too.

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```